# GeoDjango Querying location__within=poly uses Boundaries instead of Actual Shape

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I'm using GeoDjango to find all points within a Polygon but it seems to be using the Boundaries (NMW,NME,SME,SMW) to find points. So it brings back results that are outside of the primary shape.

```py
polygon = Polygon((18.3825363358424 -33.97219070578159,...))
Order.objects.filter(location__within=polygon)
```

I would like the query to bring points inside the shape and not inside its bounds.

i.e if * was my shape; I'm getting points in # that seems to suggest that it's querying on the bounds instead of the actual shape.

```
**************
**************
******########
******########
******########
```

Please tell if I'm doing some wrong?

Comment: Interestingly enough when I use the python code it works as expected.

`self.mpoly.contains(order.location)`
But I would like to do this without having to loop through each point record, I'm dealing with huge amounts fo data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like this is a MySQL Limitations

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#mysql-spatial-limitations

> In other words, while spatial lookups such as contains are available in GeoDjango when using MySQL, the results returned are really equivalent to what would be returned when using bbcontains on a different spatial backend.

:( any other way of solving this problem

Comment: If there is no specific reason to use MySQL for your project, you can start using PostgreSQL with the PostGIS.